# C#コンソールアプリでSendInputを扱いたい

Tags: c#, winapi

SendInputが動作せず悩んでいます。
環境はVisualStudio2022、C#コンソールアプリ、.Net7.0です。

主に以下のＨＰを参考に他、C#でSendInputを扱ったＨＰを見ながら作成しました。

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/f1df67f9-33a2-4293-bfe3-46d2810846f3/cwin32apinotepadpostmessagecontrol-a?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissuesja

エラーコードからパラメータの指定が間違っているのではないかと思いますが行き詰まっています。
アドバイスよろしくお願いいたします。

※メモ帳にctrl+vを送信しているため、動作にはメモ帳を起動し何かctrl+cをしておく必要があります。

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program
{
    #pragma warning disable IDE0051
    private const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
    private const int INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
    private const int INPUT_HARDWARE = 2;

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x1;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x2;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x4;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x8;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x20;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x40;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x800;
    private const int WHEEL_DELTA = 120;

    private const short VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    private const short VK_V = (short)'V';

    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    #pragma warning restore IDE0051

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public short wVk;
        public short wScan;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public int type;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    };

    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        #pragma warning disable SYSLIB1054
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string? lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildafter, string lpszClass, string? lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MapVirtualKeyA", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int MapVirtualKey(int wCode, int wMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint SendInput(int nInputs, ref INPUT[] pInputs, int cbsize);
        #pragma warning restore SYSLIB1054
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        uint rtnCode;
        int errCode;

        IntPtr hWnd1, hWnd2;
        hWnd1 = NativeMethods.FindWindow("Notepad", null);
        hWnd2 = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hWnd1, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd1);
        NativeMethods.SetFocus(hWnd2);

        INPUT defaultInput = new();
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[4];

        defaultInput.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        defaultInput.ki.wVk = 0x0;
        defaultInput.ki.wScan = 0; // (short)NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(defaultInput.ki.wVk, 0);
        defaultInput.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        defaultInput.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        defaultInput.ki.time = 0;

        inputs[0] = defaultInput;
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN;

        inputs[1] = defaultInput;
        inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_V;
        inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN;

        inputs[2] = defaultInput;
        inputs[2].ki.wVk = VK_V;
        inputs[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        inputs[3] = defaultInput;
        inputs[3].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
        inputs[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            rtnCode = NativeMethods.SendInput(4, ref inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
            errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : rtn({1}) / err({2})", ++i, rtnCode, errCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 試しては居ないのですが、SendInputの引数の`ref INPUT[] pInputs`には`ref`は不要に思えます。https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html などを参考にpinvokeの定義を見直した方が良いかと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。refをとっても変わりませんでした。

Comment: こんなライブラリがあるようですので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [michaelnoonan/inputsimulator](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator)

Comment: udakenさん、kunifさん、改めてご回答ありがとうございます。配列であればrefはいらないということでしょうか。引き続きためしているのですが煮詰まった感じです。引き続きお気づきの点がありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: INPUT 構造体が 64bit で問題になりそうです。
.NET のソースを参考にしてみては？
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,1974351c7639f8d5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まとめておきます。

(1) SendInput の第２引数

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint SendInput(int nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbsize);

udaken さんのご指摘にあるように、第２引数は ref を外してください。

(2) INPUT 構造体

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} INPUT, *PINPUT, *LPINPUT
```

32 ビットだと、type のすぐあとに MOUSEINPUT や KEYBDINPUT 等が配置されますが、
64 ビットだと 64ビット境界に配置（アライメント）されるため、空き領域ができます。
aroma さんのソースでは、FieldOffset(4) → FieldOffset(8) となります。

.NET のソースでは

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    public int type;
    public INPUTUNION inputUnion;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUTUNION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}
```

のようにアライメントを考慮した記述になっています。

Comment: 皆様ありがとうございます。
ご指摘どおり、refを取って、アライメントを行い、各構造体を見直した結果KEYBDINPUT構造体のULONG_PTR dwExtraInfoをpublic IntPtr dwExtraInfoに変更したところ無事動作しました。
まだエラー(5)「アクセスが拒否されました。」が返っていますが目的は達成したため締めたいと思います。[CsWin32]勉強になります。こちらも引き続き調べてみたいと思います。誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: GetLastError を参照するのは、エラーになったとき（戻り値がゼロのとき）だけです。
正常終了した場合、エラーコードはセットされないため、他の場所でセットされたものが入っています。

Comment: あっその通りですね。何から何まで助かります。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

動かなかった原因は、おそらくKOZさんの回答の通りだと思います。
今は、[CsWin32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32/) でP/Invokeコードを自動生成できるので、そちらを使用した方がマーシャリングや構造体の作り方等であまり悩まずに済むと思います。
NativeMethods.txtに使用するAPIを記述するだけで、関連する構造体・定数も自動生成されるので、かなり楽です。

[NativeMethods.txt]

```
SendInput
FindWindow
FindWindowEx
SetForegroundWindow
SetFocus
```

[CsWin32を使用して修正したソース]

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Threading;
using Windows.Win32.Foundation;
using Windows.Win32.UI.Input.KeyboardAndMouse;
using static Windows.Win32.PInvoke;

internal class Program
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows5.0")]
    private static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;

        var hWnd1 = FindWindow("Notepad", null);
        var hWnd2 = FindWindowEx(hWnd1, HWND.Null, "Edit", null);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd1);
        SetFocus(hWnd2);

        INPUT defaultInput = new();
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[4];

        defaultInput.type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        defaultInput.Anonymous.ki.wVk = 0x0;
        defaultInput.Anonymous.ki.wScan = 0;
        defaultInput.Anonymous.ki.dwFlags = KEYBD_EVENT_FLAGS.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYBD_EVENT_FLAGS.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        defaultInput.Anonymous.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        defaultInput.Anonymous.ki.time = 0;

        inputs[0] = defaultInput;
        inputs[0].Anonymous.ki.wVk = VIRTUAL_KEY.VK_CONTROL;
        inputs[0].Anonymous.ki.dwFlags = 0;

        inputs[1] = defaultInput;
        inputs[1].Anonymous.ki.wVk = VIRTUAL_KEY.VK_V;
        inputs[1].Anonymous.ki.dwFlags = 0;

        inputs[2] = defaultInput;
        inputs[2].Anonymous.ki.wVk = VIRTUAL_KEY.VK_V;
        inputs[2].Anonymous.ki.dwFlags = KEYBD_EVENT_FLAGS.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        inputs[3] = defaultInput;
        inputs[3].Anonymous.ki.wVk = VIRTUAL_KEY.VK_CONTROL;
        inputs[3].Anonymous.ki.dwFlags = KEYBD_EVENT_FLAGS.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            var rtnCode = SendInput(inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
            var errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : rtn({1}) / err({2})", ++i, rtnCode, errCode);
        }
    }
}
```

[CsWin32でWin32APIのプラットフォーム呼び出し(P/Invoke)コードを自動生成](https://qiita.com/radian-jp/items/a4509f9a44101fb2f30e)

Answer (score 0):

ちなみに.NETクラスライブラリにも[`SendKeys.Send`メソッド](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)が用意されていますので、Ctrl+Vぐらいなら簡単に送信できます。Ctrlキーは`^`と記述する仕様ですので、`SendKeys.Send("^v")`で実現できます。

質問文には「コンソールアプリケーション」とありますが、その場合、プロジェクトファイル（`.csproj`）に次のように記述することでWinFormsを有効化します。

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>

    <!-- コンソールアプリケーション -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

    <!-- Windowsであることを明示する -->
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>

    <!-- WinFormsを有効化 -->
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>

  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そんな方法があるとは知りませんでした！勉強になりました。